# List of components which can be deployed as a part of unlocked package

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

In sandbox 1 created one object and fields. Then changed the FLS(field level security) for one field. Added this object in a unlocked package then after versioning installed it in sandbox 2. FLS did not deployed i.e. the FLS for that field is showing some default values.
So shall we have to maintain the FLS as part of post deployment activity?

**can any one pls share the complete list of metadata which can be deployed by unlocked package.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is available in the Metadata Coverage Report:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage

However, Field Level Security is not part of the field or object itself, but part of the Profile or Permission Set where the FLS was added. So you'll have to add this metadata to your package too if you want to deploy the access.field

Comment: It should be recommended to use permission sets, though. They're much easier to use with scratch orgs.

Comment: thanks got it...